# Why is the pressure inside a fluid is equal in all directions?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

Actually, I am thinking that the fluid pressure occurs as the result of the forces acting on each molecule from each other. If it is true, then why should the horizontal force be equal to the vertical force that is connected to the pressure calculated by hρg?

And also, I want to know whether it would be the same in an accelerating water container. Since it is accelerating shouldn't there be a force difference that leads to an inequality of the pressure in different directions? If it is true, does that mean hρg won't give me the correct answer for horizontal calculations?

Furthermore, I want to know about the pressure of flowing fluids. Will there be equal pressure in all directions if the flow is at a constant speed? Will the pressure vary if it is accelerating?

Comment: what does hpg stand for?

Comment: Are you referring to Pascal's principle?

Comment: The pressure in a specific depth. We use h×ρ×g to calculate it, right? That's what I meant there.

Comment: OK.  But what makes you think the pressure is the same in all directions as stated in the title to your post? What principle are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18255/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31822/2451 and links therein.

Comment: if the fluid is in hydrostatic equilibrium, the compressive stress (which we identify as the pressure) is the same in all directions.  If the fluid is deforming, then a so-called viscous Newtonian Fluid (typical of most fluids we encounter in practice) will have unequal principal compressive stresses in the three principal (orthogonal) directions.  This is covered in a course in fluid mechanics.