# Will a metal block float in water in such a scenario?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

So I was having a doubt of why metal block sinks in water. *I was wondering why water molecules that have the capacity to exert pressures supporting the water columns at depth of say  Mariana Trench cannot lift a block of iron.*

With a bit of help, I came up with this explanation:
[image: Demonstration of the fact]

1. The block is placed in water$\implies$ Pressure on the surface molecules increases.
2. Lateral pressure is equal to upward pressure. (As aso explained in this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/why-is-pressure-in-a-liquid-the-same-in-all-directions) and this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/774321/why-is-pressure-at-a-point-inside-a-static-fluid-same-in-all-directions))
3. Moecules experiencing the extra pressure shift in other directions to regions of lower pressure(1st layer of molecules is shown by darker blue line) and the block sinks a little.
4. The shifted water, that above the second layer(& above the block) and the weight of the block increase pressure on $2^{nd}$ layer of molecules and the process(sinking) continues.
5. The reverse happens for floating.

These questions ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669362/why-does-a-fluid-push-upward-on-a-body-fully-or-partially-submerged-in-it/669370#669370) and [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597440/is-there-a-reason-behind-why-archimedes-principle-works)) seem to agree that pressure difference is the cause of upthrust.

- **Is my explanation correct?**

I am hoping it is correct, which brings us to the real question.
The same block is put in the centre of a **U-tube** (some kind of teleportation or maybe it is suspended by string that later dissolves) in this way
[image: The arrangement]

- **Given sufficient height of arms of the U-tube(columns), will even metal float?***(irrespective of density differences?)*

Comment: re: "U-tube" - Ever seen a picture of a steel ship floating in the ocean?

Comment: @MaxW That is hollow, this a solid block

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to do with pressure, it has to do with density. Ocean water varies in density from about 1.03 g/cc at the surface to 1.08 g/cc at the ocean floor. Iron, meanwhile, is 7.9 g/cc. Hence it will never float on water.

However, it might interest you to know that iron will float on mercury, which has a density of about 13 g/cc. You can see images and videos of this.

Comment: So a jet of water cannot lift iron ?

Comment: A jet of water operates on an entirely different principle than buoyancy.  In a jet, it is the momentum of the water being transferred to the object (e.g. a piece of iron) which supports the object's weight. You could even do this with a jet of air if powerful enough.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but if [link](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1G6kbrlITSsmLghq7ZNusvWn3iMnogipDzA&usqp=CAU) has a metal block placed on a hole can't pressure lift it?

Comment: I'm not sure what that picture is, but for example the reason pressurized oil can move a piston is it is only pressurized on one side, not the other. For a submerged item, the pressure is very nearly the same on all sides. There is a slight pressure difference between top and bottom that causes buoyancy, but this will never be enough to lift a solid item unless the density of the solid is lower than that of the surrounding fluid

Comment: so is my explanation of upthrust wrong?

Comment: Surface tension will allow an iron needle to float on water.

Comment: Good point______