# why is pressure more convenient than force while dealing with fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

If two equal and opposite forces act on a surface, can I say the pressure is zero because the net force is zero? How can pressure be non directional when force as a direction? How can the pressure of a liquid be explained at the molecular level in liquids? If I exert a force vertically on a liquid, why does it move sideways?

Comment: Please limit the number of questions per post to 1. If you have several questions, ask them individually.

Comment: These questions are very elementary. You want a general understanding of fluid statics. Think of a cube of fluid as full of bouncing rubber balls, and the walls are vibrating too (with temperature). That model answers all your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define Pressure at A point. Why is it a Scalar?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18255/)

Answer (score 0):

[Pressure is force per unit area.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) Pressure and force are different, though related, units of measurement

Answer (score 0):

Fluid is a continuum in which we are interested in describing flow properties as continuous function of space ( also time). So pressure will be much better representation than force.

Think about this,
     dF=p.dA here p is pressure at a point as a function of space and dF, dA are elemental force and elemental area at a point. Give it a thought it will be more clear.